# Percentage completion calculator swift

Tags: swift, xcode, counter

So, I have 14 checkmarks in total and I want to press one and have a number calculate the overall completion for all the checkmarks(14 in total).

I researched through the web and I tried to solved it like this...First, I thought I needed to declare two variables; one for the counter and another for the total (14) , then  I declare a constant (which would represent my total value * 100 , and I will finally do the percentage calculation.

My problem comes when I have to define what the overall percentage is calculated.

Code is here:

```
import UIKit   

var checkmarksDouble: Float = 100.0 //this is my total on percentage
var totalCheckmarksCounted: Float = 14.0 //my total on checkmarks
var counter: Float = + 1  //Counter


let perCent = 100*counter/(checkmarksDouble + counter) 
var perCentCGFloat =  CGFloat(perCent)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Percentage of what? Do you mean if 7 check marks are checked we should get 50 %?

Comment: yes, what I want to calculate is the completion of the 14 checkmarks expressed on percentages

Comment: So you want the number of checked boxes divided by 14 multiplied by 100.

Comment: ok, thanks for your tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u want to calculate total percentage according to checkmark.

```
 var checkmarksDouble: Float = 100.0 //this is my total on percentage
    var totalCheckmarksCounted: Float = 14.0 //my total on checkmarks
    var counter: Float =  0  //Counter
    var perCentCGFloat:Float =  0
    var percentageOfOneCheckmark:Float = 0
```

now calculate percentage for single checkmark

```
 percentageOfOneCheckmark = checkmarksDouble / totalCheckmarksCounted
```

call this method when you click checkmark

```
  func checkmarkClickForCalculaationPercentage() -> Void
{
    counter += 1
    perCentCGFloat = percentageOfOneCheckmark *counter
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: @CVar https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work